# Data change Capture in Redshift using AWS Glue script

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I have used a "For in" loop script in AWS Glue to move 70 tables from S3 to Redshift. But, When I run the script again and again, data is being duplicated. I have seen one document as a solution for this.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sql-commands-redshift-glue-job/
But, In my case, As I am using "for in" loop script for moving tables together, How can I Make use of creating staging table concept as in the document?

Here is the script I am using for moving tables to redshift:

```
client = boto3.client("glue", region_name="us-east-1")

databaseName = "db1_g"
Tables = client.get_tables(DatabaseName=databaseName)
tableList = Tables["TableList"]

for table in tableList:
    tableName = table["Name"]
    datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
        database="db1_g", table_name=tableName, transformation_ctx="datasource0"
    )

    datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
        frame=datasource0,
        catalog_connection="redshift",
        connection_options={
            "dbtable": f"schema1.{tableName}",
            "database": "db1",
        },
        redshift_tmp_dir=args["TempDir"],
        transformation_ctx="datasink4",
    )
job.commit()
```

Is there any way to avoid duplicating data when we use loop script for moving tables?

Comment: Do you want to upsert or update?

Comment: I want to Upsert.

Comment: @RobertKossendey Could you help if you have knowledge in this?